# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(StringCon))
{
    string sSQL = string.Format("UPDATE Guest SET FirstName=@Content WHERE GuestID=@GuestID");
    SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection1);
    SqlParameter param = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    param.Value = "Tony";
    SqlParameter param1 = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@GuestID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    param1.Value = GuestID;
    connection1.Open();
    iResult = MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection1.Close();
}
```

But this code cannot execute because this error

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why have error and how to fix it.

Comment: What happens when you run that statement by hand?  Maybe there's a trigger on the table taking too long, or there's no index on the table, or the table is locked, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that this command is taking longer than you anticipated, you can try to specify the timeout for your SqlCommand (extend it to whatever you see fit for the situation):

```
SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection1);
MyCmd.CommandTimeout = 1000; // in seconds
```

Comment: I try it but cannot execute :(, anything else answer

Comment: If you run the same command but directly on the DB server, how long does it take you ? Maybe you need to index your table. You can try to increase the CommandTimeout.

Comment: I try execute the query in SQL Server 2008, it process so fast, but i use the code execute very hard, I don't know how long time out.

Comment: Could you please show me your connection string ?

Comment: Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=ID Name ;Password=pass;

Comment: Ok I did some digging around, and maybe you can try to clear your SQL statistics (on SQL run this command : `exec sp_updatestats`)

Comment: Hi Dimitar Dimitrov
I executed sp_updatestats but cannot execute the code, so anything else solution.